# read a text file, make some trivial transformation character by character (swapping the case of all letters), write result to text file

Tags: c, string, file

I have to read a text file, make some trivial transformation character by character (swapping the case of all letters), write results to the text files. I wrote this code, but it's not working. Please guide me in this regard. Thanks for in Advance

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
int main() {
    char c[1000];
     char x[100];
     char var;
     int i;
    FILE *fptr;
    if ((fptr = fopen("text.txt", "r")) == NULL) {
        printf("Error! opening file");
        // Program exits if file pointer returns NULL...
        exit(1);
    }

    // reads text until a newline is encountered...
    fscanf(fptr, "%[^\n]", c);
    printf("Data from the file:\n%s", c);
    // Convert the file to upper case....
     
    for( i=0;i<= strlen(c);i++){
      if(c[i]>=65&&c[i]<=90)
         c[i]=c[i]+32;
   }
      fptr = fopen("program.txt","w");
      fprintf(fptr,"%[^\n]",c);
     
      fclose(fptr);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit: added `#include <stdlib.h>`, removed `static` describing `main()`

My proposition, based on example of copying a file given at my uni.

I used toupper() from ctype.h, if you don't want to use it you can just add 32 under condition similarly to your solution

Note: there could be `char c` instead of `int c`. (In the original version it actually was `char`; I changed it because if you look at the headers in the docs of all functions dealing with `c`, they all take/return `int`, not `char`; in your version it would matter more as you keep an array, in my program it changes pretty much nothing – `int` is just my preferred practice).

Note2: I actually never delved into the difference between "w"/"r" (write/read) and "wb"/"rb" (write/read *binary*). The code seems to work either way.

(I think there is no big difference when the files are text files anyway, for further assurance that both versions work, note that the code uses feof() to handle EOF)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void) {
    FILE *from, *to;
    int c;//could be char
    
    /* opening the source file */
    if ((from = fopen("text.txt", "rb")) == NULL) {
        printf("no such source file\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    
    /* opening the target file */
    if ((to = fopen("program.txt", "wb")) == NULL) {
        printf("error while opening target file\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    
    while (!feof(from)) {
        c = fgetc(from);
        
        if (ferror(from)) {
            printf("error while reading from the source file\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        
        if (!feof(from)) {//we avoid writing EOF
            fputc(toupper(c), to);
            if (ferror(to)) {
                printf("error while writing to the target file\n");
                exit(1);
            }
        }
    }
    
    if (fclose(from) == EOF) {
        printf("error while closing...\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    
    
    if (fclose(to) == EOF) {
        printf("error while closing...\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

For a version taking arguments from command line (works on windows too) replace the beginning of main with

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    FILE *from, *to;
    char c;

    /* checking the number of arguments in the command line */
    if (argc != 3) {
        printf("usage: name_of_executable_of_this_main <f1> <f2>\n");//name_of_exe could be copy_to_upper, for example; change adequately
        exit(1);
    }
    
    /* opening the source file */
    if ((from = fopen(argv[1], "rb")) == NULL) {
        printf("no such source file\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    
    /* opening the target file */
    if ((to = fopen(argv[2], "wb")) == NULL) {
        printf("error while opening the target file\n");
        exit(1);
    }
```

Comment: Funnily enough, my 'exercise teacher' taught us to use `int`, and the professor used `char` in lecture; the main problem with char is, that `(char)-1` can be valid character while `(int)-1` is EOF. It doesn't matter here: I use `feof()` (following professor's recommendation)  so no monkey business with `(c == EOF)`, which I'm pretty sure doesn't work with "rb" anyway

Comment: `int c;//could be char`?!?  No, it **can't** be a `char`.  `[f]getc()` returns `int` and not `char` because `EOF` doesn't fit into a `char`.

Comment: it was char in the original version, and it worked fine, as it should – note that I don't check if the result `[f]getc()` is EOF anywhere. I agree though, it's better practice to use int

Comment: Checked on linux, and even `gcc -Wall -Wextra` doesn't say a word. Well, I hope anyone reading my answer can see that, it's **not the best to use char**, and that **it's good to use feof()** so you don't really need to worry about it much.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know how to code in that language(i think it's C++), but basically want you should be doing is a for loop to iterate through every character in the string. In Python it would look like:

```
x = open("text.txt", "r")
y = open("new text.txt","w")
z = ""
for char in x:
    z += char.upper()
    
y.write(z)
```

I hope I was able to give an idea of how to solve your problem. I'm a newbie as well, but in Python.

Comment: Sir, I have written this code in C language and its requirements are   1_ read a text file       2_ change the case of letters after reading the file                      3_ then save that result in a file. But my code is only reading files and saving brackets in the write part. Now, tell me if you have any idea about this.

Comment: Open the file to a variable, Use a for loop to iterate through every character in the variable and convert them to upper case, and then write the converted variable into a blank text file.

Comment: Don't use magic numbers. 32 and 65 are not your friends. `islower` and `toupper` are.

Comment: Never, **EVER** use (f)scanf to read a line (Or anything else for that matter). Use `fgets`, *check the return value*, process, use `fputs`, *check the return value*.